# Why api route cannot use Auth::logout laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6

Now, I'm using `api.php` route for requests from **Axios** on **VueJS** , And I need to logout from `Auth::guard('web')->logout();` command but, at the moment, I cannot do this.

**routes/api.php**

```php
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'v1/auth', 'middleware' => 'jwt'], function () { //
  Route::get('me', 'Auth\UserController@me');
  Route::get('gg', 'Auth\UserController@test');
});
```

**app/Http/sMiddleware/JwtMiddleware.php**

```php
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RefreshToken extends BaseMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


        try
        {
            if (! $user = JWTAuth::toUser(JWTAuth::getToken()))
            {
                return response()->json([
                'code'   => 101, // means auth error in the api,
                'response' => 'not authenticate' // nothing to show 
                ]);
            }
        }
        catch (TokenExpiredException $e)
        {
            // If the token is expired, then it will be refreshed and added to the headers
            try
            {
                $refreshed = JWTAuth::refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());
                header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $refreshed);
            }
            catch (JWTException $e)
            {
                return response()->json([
                'code'   => 103, // means not refreshable 
                'response' => 'token jwt exception' // nothing to show 
                ]);
            }
        }
        catch (JWTException $e)
        {

            Auth::guard('web')->logout(); // here

            return response()->json([
                'code'   => 101, // means auth error in the api,
                'response' => 'jwterror' // nothing to show 
            ]);
        }

        return  $next($request);
    }
}
```

But when i migrated from `api.php` to `web.php`. I can use **Axios** to post for logout

Please, tell me how to use `Auth::logout` in api route file.

Sorry I'm not good at english.

Answer (score 0):

Logout is implemented with the `session driver`, and unlike there **web guard**, the **api guard** is using a `token driver` not session driver.

Basically, the user is not logged into the API, but WEB part of your application.

In the api; find a way to **[invalidate/expire](https://medium.com/@mosesesan/tutorial-5-how-to-build-a-laravel-5-4-jwt-authentication-api-with-e-mail-verification-61d3f356f823)** the token so that the user with that token can no longer access the api resources.

```
try {
   JWTAuth::invalidate($request->input('token'));
   return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message'=> "You have successfully logged out."]);
} catch (JWTException $e) {
   // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
   return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Failed to logout, please try again.'], 500);
}
```

[Web logout](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L153)

[Session Logout](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L484)

Comment: i can find a way out. but i need when user have no token in localstorage or wrong token will be logout automatically.Now i used login from Auth::guard('web')